# Unable to install jasmine-core in npm Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ubuntu, jasmine

I'm having some problems to install **Jasminejs**. I'll really appreciate some help please. Thanks!

*First I run this:*

**npm install karma-cli -g**

I don't get any errors with this command.

*After running this command:*

**npm install jasmine-core --save-dev**

*I'm getting this messages:*

jasmine-core@2.4.1

UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY karma@

npm warn optional skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents

npm warn notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12

npm warn karma-jasmine@1.0.2 requires a peer of karma@* but none was installed.

npm warn karma phantomjs-launcher@1.0.0 requires a peer of  karma@>=0.9 but none was installed

*If I try to run this command:*

**npm install phantomjs-prebuilt --save**

I' getting a similar error message. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.4, Node 5.10.1 and npm 3.10.2 .

Comment: `npm warn notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12` is the big problem here. Check on what conflicts it has with your software/hardware.

Comment: @max Did you find the solution to this? I am also getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You met 'UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY' issue is because NPM3 no longer gets dependencies automatically. You should put missing dependency on the same install command line despite you have already installed the package.

e.g. npm install jasmine-core karma --save-dev